# Java Swing exercise - Can't access variable, don't know why

Tags: java

I'm learning Java development and for a homework assignment I've been instructed to code a basic application using the Swing framework. The set-up is pretty simple: an application that picks two cards (Strings) from a card deck (Arraylist), and let's the user guess if the second card is higher or lower than the first.

Piece of cake, right? So I thought as well, until I stumbled upon a problem: I've linked an action to a button, and the action does get executed, but I can't seem to access a variable I initiated in my application while processing the action. Take a look at the action "Gok hoger", it returns a null value for "kaart1". Yet, when I echo the String "kaart1" in my Program constructor, it's filled in fine. I'm clueless as to the cause of this... so I'm hoping some of the brilliant minds here can explain to me why my code behaves like this.

```
if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Gok hoger")){
    System.out.println(kaart1); // <------- Why does this return null?
}
```

Yes, it's a homework assignment, and I've tagged it as such just in case.

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class Programma extends JFrame {

    ArrayList<String> kaartboek = new ArrayList<String>();
    boolean gewonnen = false;
    int kaart1waarde;
    int kaart2waarde;
    String kaart1;
    String kaart2;

    public Programma(){
        super("Hoger/lager");

        vulKaartboek(kaartboek);
        String kaart1 = new String(trekKaart(kaartboek));
        String kaart2 = new String(trekKaart(kaartboek));

        JButton hogerButton = new JButton("Hoger");
        JButton lagerButton = new JButton("Lager");
        hogerButton.setAction(new Actie("Gok hoger"));
        lagerButton.setAction(new Actie("Gok lager"));

        JLabel kaart1label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(
            "/Users/David/Dropbox/School/eclipse/2011/VGO_Opdracht1/src/kaartboek/"
            + kaart1 +".png"));
        JLabel kaart2label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(
            "/Users/David/Dropbox/School/eclipse/2011/VGO_Opdracht1/src/kaartboek/"
            + "back" + ".png"));

        Container c = getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
        c.add(kaart1label);
        c.add(kaart2label);
        c.add(hogerButton);
        c.add(lagerButton);

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main (String args[]){
        JFrame frame1 = new Programma();
    }

    public String getKaartSuit(String kaart){
        String kaart1suit = kaart.substring(0, 1);
        if(kaart1suit.equals("c")){kaart1suit = "Klaveren";}
        if(kaart1suit.equals("d")){kaart1suit = "Ruiten";}
        if(kaart1suit.equals("h")){kaart1suit = "Harten";}
        if(kaart1suit.equals("s")){kaart1suit = "Schoppen";}
        return kaart1suit;
    }

    public String getKaartBeeld(String kaart){
        int kaartwaarde = Integer.parseInt(kaart.substring(1, kaart.length()));
        String kaartbeeld = "";
        switch(kaartwaarde){
            case 2: kaartbeeld = "Twee"; break;
            case 3: kaartbeeld = "Drie"; break;
            case 4: kaartbeeld = "Vier"; break;
            case 5: kaartbeeld = "Vijf"; break;
            case 6: kaartbeeld = "Zes"; break;
            case 7: kaartbeeld = "Zeven"; break;
            case 8: kaartbeeld = "Acht"; break;
            case 9: kaartbeeld = "Negen"; break;
            case 10: kaartbeeld = "Tien"; break;
            case 11: kaartbeeld = "Boer"; break;
            case 12: kaartbeeld = "Dame"; break;
            case 13: kaartbeeld = "Heer"; break;
            case 14: kaartbeeld = "Aas"; break;
        }
        return kaartbeeld;
    }

    public String getKaartNaam(String kaart){
        String kaartnaam = getKaartSuit(kaart) + " " + getKaartBeeld(kaart);
        return kaartnaam;
    }

    public String trekKaart(ArrayList<String> kaartboek){
        Random random = new Random();
        int willekeurig = random.nextInt(kaartboek.size());

        String kaart = kaartboek.get(willekeurig);
        kaartboek.remove(willekeurig);

        return kaart;
    }

    public void vulKaartboek(ArrayList kaartboek){
        for(int i = 2; i < 14; i++){
            kaartboek.add("c" + i); // Clubs
            kaartboek.add("d" + i); // Diamonds
            kaartboek.add("h" + i); // Hearts
            kaartboek.add("s" + i); // Spades
        }
    }

    public int getKaartWaarde(String kaart){
        int kaartwaarde = Integer.parseInt(kaart.substring(1, kaart.length()));
        return kaartwaarde;
    }

    class Actie extends AbstractAction  { // Inner klasse
        public Actie(String s){
            super(s); 
        }
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Gok hoger")){
                System.out.println(kaart1); // <------- Why does this return null?

                }
            if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Gok lager")){
                System.out.println("Test");
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for sscce http://sscce.org/ although the images are irrelevant.

Comment: Reformatted code; please revert if incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two variables called kaart1. One is local to the Programma constructor. The one accessed in "Actie" is the instance variable.

You probably meant to not declare a second variable in the constructor, but instead initialize the instance variable. Replace "String kaart1 = new String(trekKaart(kaartboek));" with "kaart1 = new String(trekKaart(kaartboek));"

Comment: It's amazing how clear some things can become. I was look for a far more complex cause. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

You get null because you are using local variables in here:

```
    String kaart1 = new String(trekKaart(kaartboek));
```

replace with

```
    this.kaart1 = new String(trekKaart(kaartboek));
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, the problem revolves around [*Hiding Fields*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html). In addition, consider programming to the interface:

```
List<String> kaartboek = new ArrayList<String>();
```

In `trekKaart()`, don't instantiate `Random()` repeatedly. Instead shuffle the deck once:

```
Collections.shuffle(kaartboek);
```

Then you can retrieve random cards easily using a simpler `trekKaart()`:

```
kaart1 = trekKaart(kaartboek, 1);
kaart2 = trekKaart(kaartboek, 2);

private String trekKaart(List<String> kaartboek, int index) {
    return kaartboek.get(index);
}
```

Finally, `trekKaart()` and `vulKaartboek()` are called from the `Programma` constructor, so they should be private.

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor you are declaring two new kaart objects. The inner class is trying to access the old kaart variables which are not assigned hence "null"

```
String kaart1;
String kaart2;

public Programma(){
    super("Hoger/lager");

    vulKaartboek(kaartboek);
    String kaart1 = new String(trekKaart(kaartboek)); // You shoud initialize it as this.kaart1
    String kaart2 = new String(trekKaart(kaartboek)); // You shoud initialize it as this.kaart2

}
```

Answer (score -2):

variable kaart1 is not declared in class Actie. Thats why it is null. Your code is hard to read for me(partly your language partly design), so i don't exactly know what you are trying to do.